# Getting current logged in user - NestJS

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

So. I set up a `DELETE`method for deleting Rents (a `Rent` happens when a `User` rents out an `Item` in my database).

I would like to make sure to check that the only user that can cancel the rent is the one that actually rented the item. I already implemented a check that prevents the user to rent an item from himself.

So basically before executing the delete query on that row in `Rents` table, i want to check that the ID of the current logged in user matches with the userID of that specific row in `Rents` table, only then will the query be executed

**Rents table entry example**
[image]

userId is the ID of the `User` that rented an `Item` (itemId).

I set up a **custom `GetUser()` decorator**

```
import { User } from './../entities/user.entity';
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const GetUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data, ctx: ExecutionContext): User => {
    const req = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return req.user;
  },
);
```

Now, when i call my `getMyItems`method to get all the items that the current user owns, the `GetUser()`decorator works fine as i can access the user on the request object.

**GetMyItems controller**

```
  @Get('/my')
  @ApiBearerAuth()
  async getMyItems(@GetUser() user: User): Promise<Item[]> {
    return this.itemsService.getMyItems(user);
  }
```

When I try to do the same for the mentioned `cancelRent` method it doesn't seem to work even though everything is setup the same way.

**cancelRent controller**

```
@Delete('/:id/cancel')
  async cancelRent(
    @Param('id') id: number,
    @GetUser() user: User,
  ): Promise<void> {
    return this.rentsService.cancelRent(id, user);
  }
```

When i run `console.log(user)` in the cancelRent controller i get `undefined`, but when I run it in the getMyItems method it returns the current user normally. Is it because its a `DELETE` request and not a `GET` request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to include AuthGuard() in my Rents Controller.

Answer (score 0):

`cancelRent()` is missing `@ApiBearerAuth()`

Comment: @ApiBearerAuth() is for swagger purposes. It doesn't impact the code in any way, i think? I just tried and it doesn't work with it

Comment: Ah okay, you might be right. What authentication mechanism are you using? Are you sure you sent the user credentials that are required for authentication in cancelRent-request?

Comment: Im using JWT auth. I was hoping that the getUser() custom decorator would do the job of sending the user credentials, or at least some info like the ID

Comment: Did you read the [guide on authentication](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)? Your custom decorator just extracts a property `user` from the Http-Request object. The decorator itself will not trigger the authentication mechanism. You need a `Guard` for that.

Comment: I posted an answer. I forgot the add the AuthGuard() in my Rents Controller. This prevented me to fetch User from the request because it was simply not passed through